# Best way to create properties in ExtJS4?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs

I'm wondering how to incorporate a more traditional property class into ExtJS 4's dynamic loading?  In Ext3, I would create a set of properties as follows:

```
org.config.appName = "appname";
org.config.browser = {};
org.config.browser.Browsers = [
    {
        name: 'Chrome',
        ....
    }
];
```

Imagine also that I would have created a set of extended objects under org:

```
org.foo = Ext.extend('Ext.Panel', {
    ...
});
```

In Ext4, when I load the properties, org has not been created and so throws an error.  This leaves me with, I believe, two ways to fix the problem:

1. Define org:  `if(typeof org === 'undefined') { org = {}; }`
2. Dynamically load the properties as a singleton:

   ```
   Ext.define('org.config',{
       singleton: true,
       appName: "appname",
       browser: {
           Browsers: [
               {
                   name: 'Chrome',
                   ...
               },
               ...
           ]
       }
   });
   ```

How would option 1 affect the dynamically loaded objects?  Is option 2 the best way to create a set of properties?  Am I missing a third, better option?  Appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 should work just fine for you.

Regardless of Ext versions JavaScript won't let you create your "namespaces" objects without first creating the root object and so on. Ext had namespace function that was used to create one for your overall app. Since 4.0 use Ext.application to setup your namespace and Ext.define to create name-spaced classes.

I am not quite clear what you mean by dynamically loaded objects ...

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up going with option 2.  In regards to dynamic loading (incorrectly termed on my part), I was referring primarily to the new component model in version 4 (i.e. `Ext.define('org.obj',{});`) that abstracts "namespace" resolution.

Comment: You may want to read this guide http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/class_system